# Is it possible to do a double replace?

Tags: javascript, replace

If double replace is it possible to do?

```
var string = [link="<iframe"qwe"></iframe>"]

var output = string.replace(/[link="([^"]+)"]/g, '$1.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, "'")');
```

what i want output:

```
[link="<iframe'qwe'></iframe>"]
```

Comment: None of this is jQuery.  It's all javascript.

Comment: Also the value for `string` is invalid syntax.

Comment: You have a syntax error, you need to escape quotes that are inside a string, or use different quotes as the delimiters.

Comment: The `[ ...]` around the value makes it an array, not a string. Did you mean `string[0].replace`?

Comment: string random word :) only text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function as the replacement in `replace()`. It can then do its own replace on the capture group.

```js
var string = '[link="<iframe"qwe"></iframe>"]';
var output = string.replace(/link="([^\]]+)"]/g, (match, group1) => 
    'link="' + group1.replace(/"/g, "'") + '"]');
console.log(output);
```

Note also that I had to correct your regexp. `([^"]+)` should be `([^\]]+)` so that it can match a string containing double quotes -- you need to capture that so you can replace the double quotes.

And in the second replacement, you want to match `"`, not `[^"]+`